# Regex with repeating group in any order

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I need help setting up a regex that has a very specific start, with a capturing group, and then other groups that can be in any order.

Example:

`c/category-name/f-brand-super-brand/f-hair-porosity-POR`

category => category-name

f-brand => super-brand

f-hair-porosity => POR

`c/exampleC/f-brand-brandY/f-hair-porosity-my-porosity`

category => exampleC

f-brand => brandY

f-hair-porosity => my-porosity

---

This is how far I've come:
`(f-(brand|hair-porosity|shampoo-type)?-?(.*?)(\/|$))`

By using this regex I can find the matches I need and it works in any given f-xxx order.

However the problem I am facing is that I can't capture the category name. All my attempts result in either capturing just the first f-xxx or the last f-xxx.

Any ideas?

This will go in a wordpress add_rewrite_url, so I need it to be a one liner.

Comment: Your regex has 4 capturing groups. Please explain what they should capture in case of category?

Comment: Can you also come back to me on my question here?

Comment: I need to capture the category and sub-category name (if it exists) as one group. I am not an expert, so I might have created more groups than necessary tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category prefix has a different pattern, ending with a forward slash (`c/`), so you should add an option for that.

I would suggest this regular expression:

```
(\bc\/|\bf-brand-|\bf-hair-porosity-|\bf-shampoo-type-)((?:(?!\/f-).)*)
```

This will capture two groups:

```
* the prefix
* the value
```

It will allow `/` to occur inside a single match when it is not followed by ´f-´. This is where a subcategory could be included in the category match.

Comment: Hi trincot, this is it, but I realised there is another pattern (subcategories) that I can't find:

c/category-name/sub-category-name/f-brand-super-brand/f-hair-porosity-POR.

I tried adding it to the one you provided but it didn't work.

Comment: So what is the variable part this "/sub-category-name"? Is it the "name" part, or the whole part? Also: which of the two solutions I gave do you want me to continue with?

Comment: the urls will be something like

/c/category/f-brand-xxxx/f-hair-porosity-oooo/....
and
/c/category/subcategory/f-shampoo-type-aaaa/f-brand-www/...

I don't need to distinguish between a category and a category/subcategory if that helps.

(\bc\/|\bf-brand-|\bf-hair-porosity-|\bf-shampoo-type-)([^\/]*) => was the one closer to what I was envisioning from the start.

Comment: let me rephrase. I need to capture the category(+subcatetory) and the f-xxx-yyy regardless of the order. was I able to explain?

Comment: OK, so if there is a subcategory, you want one match that includes both, including the slash separator in the middle?

Comment: *"regardless of the order"*: but is it assured that the category always comes first?